# String echo without if

Tags: php, string, random, echo

I have like 50 strings.

```
$rand = rand(0,50);

$name[1] = "Jane";
$name[2] = "Marienne";
...
...
...
$name[50] = "Mary";

echo $name[$rand];
```

I want to echo "Marienne" if $rand=="2" for example. But the code above is not working. And I don't want to use if statement because there are too many strings. What do you suggest me ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any error message? Are you sure that `0` is not being selected as the random number? Because you do not have a zero key in the array. Just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code should work if you don't have "DOH" moments like an uninitialized `$name[0]` key.

However, if you want to avoid that problem altogether you could use the [`array_rand`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function to pick out a (pseudo) random array key:

```
$names = array('Peter', 'Paul', 'John');
echo $names[array_rand($names)];
```

Alternatively, instead of hard-coding in `50` as your max in the random range, why not try:

```
rand(0, count($names)-1);
```